# How to find position of nonzero elements in each row?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given a matrix `A` is

```
A=[  0     1     1
     1     0     1]
```

How can I find the location of nonzeros in each row of the A matrix, without using loop. The expected result likes

```
output=[2 3
        1 3]
```

I was used `find` function but it return the unexpected result likes

```
 output=[2
         3
         5
         6]
```

Comment: What if there are variable number of non-zeros per row and not necessarily two per row?

Comment: We can have more than two rows. I just show a simple case. And we only have two non-zero values in each row, other is zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the column indices in a flattened array and then reshape -

```
[c,~] = find(A.')
out = reshape(c,[],size(A,1)).'
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     0     1     1
     1     0     1
     1     1     0
>> [c,~] = find(A.');
>> reshape(c,[],size(A,1)).'
ans =
     2     3
     1     3
     1     2
```

---

**Approach #2**

We could avoid the transposing of the input array, with some sorting -

```
[r,c]  = find(A);
[~,idx] = sort(r);
out = reshape(c(idx),[],size(A,1)).'
```

---

### Benchmarking

We will tile the rows to form a bigger input matrix and test out the proposed methods.

Benchmarking code -

```
% Setup input array
A0 = [ 0 1 1;1 0 1;1,1,0;1,0,1];
N = 10000000; % number of times to tile the input rows to create bigger one
A = A0(randi(size(A0,1),N,1),:);

disp('----------------------------------- App#1')
tic,
[c,~] = find(A.');
out = reshape(c,[],size(A,1)).';
toc
clear c out

disp('----------------------------------- App#2')
tic,
[r,c]  = find(A);
[~,idx] = sort(r);
out = reshape(c(idx),[],size(A,1)).';
toc
clear r c idx out

disp('----------------------------------- Wolfie soln')
tic,
[row, col] = find(A);
[~, idx] = sort(row);
out = [col(idx(1:2:end)), col(idx(2:2:end))];
toc
```

Timings -

```
----------------------------------- App#1
Elapsed time is 0.273673 seconds.
----------------------------------- App#2
Elapsed time is 0.973667 seconds.
----------------------------------- Wolfie soln
Elapsed time is 0.979726 seconds.
```

It's hard to choose between `App#2` and @Wolfie's soln as the timings seem comparable, but the first one seems quite efficient.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But compared with the loop (scan row by row and use find), do you think which one is better (faster)?

Comment: @Jame I would think the approaches being vectorized would be faster than looping. Feel free to time those at your end though to verify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I found the reshape function and I am not sure if it may be affected to the vectorized approach

Comment: @Jame Reshape would be virtually free. The only bottleneck could be the transpose later on.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this just with `find` and `sort`. I will use the same test example as Divakar's answer for continuity.

```
% Set up some matrix with only 2 non-zero elements per row
A = [ 0     1     1
      1     0     1
      1     1     0 ];

% Find rows/columns of non-zero elements
[row, col] = find(A);
% Get sort indices, should be two of each row value (for two non-zero elems)
[~, idx] = sort(row);
% Concatenate horizontally the first and second column indices from each row
out = [col(idx(1:2:end)), col(idx(2:2:end))];

>> disp(out)
>> [2     3
    1     3
    1     2]
```

By comparison to Divakar's solution, both methods perform the same `sort` operation, but this method doesn't require any transposes or reshaping. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46522918/3978545) for benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks. It faster 1.5x time than Divakar. :). But for larger matrix, I guess it will be bigger

Comment: @Jame Added timings in my post.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 columns you can use this method:

```
x = [1 2;1 3;2 3];
output = x((A *(0:2).').',:);
```

Result of @Divakar's benchmark in octave:

```
----------------------------------- App#1
Elapsed time is 0.813956 seconds.
----------------------------------- App#2
Elapsed time is 0.9617 seconds.
----------------------------------- Wolfie soln
Elapsed time is 1.49294 seconds.
----------------------------------- rahnema1 soln
Elapsed time is 0.221258 seconds.
```

We can generalize it to other column sizes:

```
x=nchoosek(1:size(A,2),2);
output = x((A *(0:size(A,2)-1).').',:);
```

or

```
[a b]=find(tril(true(size(A,2)),-1));
idx = (A *(0:size(A,2)-1).').';
output=[b(idx) a(idx)];
```

Comment: How are you generating `x` in this example?

Comment: `x=nchoosek(1:size(A,2),2);` or `[a b]=find(tril(true(size(A,2)),-1));`

Comment: I suspect that `nchoosek` operation gets expensive for `A` with many columns?

Comment: Yes it is. But in some conditions we may want to generate `x` only one time and use it multiple times.